# "error: failed to push some refs to 'Origin'" al hacer push

Tags: git, github

Hace días intento subir mi proyecto a GitHub y cuando llego en un cierto lugar me envia el mensaje de error . no sé si debería pro....he añadido una imagen para que vean el lugar por donde me pone el error .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los pasos fueron .(inicie en Git Bash Here )

```
git init
git status
git remote add origin link......
git add*
git status
git commit -m "mi primera pagina web"
```

y para subir

```
$ git push origin master
error: failed to push some refs to 'Origin'
```

el repositorio todo esta bien no  también desde alla me dieron algunos pasos a seguir y los he utilizado también

no sé si eso puede afectar también ya que no sé qué paso pero mi GitHub no es visible para el publico

Comment: Has intentado con `git push --set-upstream origin master` ?

Comment: copia en texto, las imágenes no se ven bien

Comment: Te falta configurar tu usuario y correo con 'git config --global' y tambien indica que no existe el origin, puedes verificarlo con 'git remote -v'

Comment: Lenovo@JANEB MINGW32 ~/Desktop/CSSP WEB (master)
$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo siguiente: Los pasos que hicistes para subir tu proyecto y el error que te salio

Answer (score 0):

Me paso el mismo error, y seguramente ya lo hayas solucionado luego de 11 meses, pero encontre una solucion probando los comandos desde git bash, capaz a alguno le sirva y tenga el mismo problema:

```
git pull --rebase origin tuBranch (ejemplo master)
git push origin tuBranch (ejemplo master)
```

*Edit:
Perdon, recien veo tu imagen, solo vi el error que figuraba, tendrias que unicamente agregar a la conifugaracion global de git(repositorio local), tu nombre de usuario y tu mail que tengas vinculado a GitHub, como bien dice en tu linea de comandos de git. Saludos.